# Separate words in the textbox C#

Tags: c#, string, text, split, textbox

I want to write a text like this in the text box: "Sentence1::Sentence2::Sentence3" and Then separate it to three parts and put them in three separately strings. I used string.split method but I couldn't put them to strings.

```
string authors = "Sentence1::Sentence2::Sentence3";
string[] authorsList = authors.Split("::");
```

Comment: What do you mean by "couldn't put them to strings?"

Comment: Any reason you can't just use the string array you created? Why do you need to put them into other string variables? You can access them by their index like Idle_Mind showed you.

Comment: You have the 3 strings: authorList[0], authorList[1] and authorList[2]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an ARRAY of Strings after the Split().  You access the strings by index.  Here's an example:

```
string authors = "Sentence1::Sentence2::Sentence3";
string[] authorsList = authors.Split("::");

for(int i=0; i<authorsList.Length; i++) {
  Console.WriteLine(i + ": " + authorsList[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
0: Sentence1
1: Sentence2
2: Sentence3
```